# Faster way to convert datetime rows of DataFrame according to timezone column

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have below sample DataFrame `df` which has two columns, viz., `datetime` column `datetime_without_tz` which doesn't have timezone information. The other column `tz_as_string` has timezone information as a `string` field.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_date = datetime(1990, 1, 1, 21, 31, 1)
ndays = 250  #Change this to million to see slow speed.
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_without_tz':[start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(ndays)], 'tz_as_string':['Europe/Berlin' for x in range(ndays)]})
```

I want to transform `datetime_without_tz` from `tz_as_string` to say `'Europe/London'`. **Note: my real `df` could have millions of rows so speed is crucial and is bottleneck here.**

**My slow solution**:

```
from pytz import timezone
df.loc[:, 'date_in_new_tz'] = [timezone(df['tz_as_string'][i]).localize(df['date_without_tz'][i]) for i in df.index]
df.loc[:, 'date_in_new_tz'] = [(df['date_in_new_tz'][i]).astimezone(timezone('Europe/London')) for i in df.index]
df.loc[:, 'date_in_new_tz'] = [(df['date_in_new_tz'][i]).replace(tzinfo=None) for i in df.index]
```

Comment: anyone to try this?

Comment: Looks like you're using pytz.  Have you tried other timezone libraries such as dateutil?

Comment: Is there an equivalent function in dateutil? Can you suggest which one?

Comment: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not think pytz.timezone is bottleneck here. I think its basically the for 3 loop iterations.